# How should I [coerce] the [type-coercion] [coercion]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

With [type-conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-conversion), [data-type-conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-type-conversion), and [type-converting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-converting), I'm just having trouble [coerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coerce)ing the [type-coercion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-coercion) [coercion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coercion). What should I do about that? Should I be [casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/casting) lots?

Subtlety: there are several different ways the words "coercion", "conversion", and "casting" are used in different languages and contexts. The current tags, however, do not appear to break along *any* natural lines.

Comment: `type-conversion`, `data-type-conversion` and `type-converting` obviously should be merged. Equally obviously so should `coerce`, `type-coercion` and `coercion`. With the remaining three tags `[type-]conversion`, `[type-]coercion` and `[type-]casting`, I'd be hesitant to merge any further. At least to me, these are not synonyms.

Comment: See also:  [tag:promotion], [tag:type-promotion] and [tag:integer-promotion] referring to implicit type changes to larger (in bytes) types.

Answer (score 14):

I'm not certain but I understood the words to mean:

- coercion: implicit conversion of one type to another where allowed by a language (eg, `1.0 + 2`)
- casting: explicit conversion of one type to another using a language feature (eg `(int)"4"`)
- conversion: both of the above, plus other kinds (like `atoi()`).

So [5gon12eder's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1392132/5gon12eder) [suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311824/how-should-i-coerce-the-type-coercion-coercion?#comment-280196) seems sound.

> [type-conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-conversion), [data-type-conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-type-conversion) and [type-converting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-converting) obviously
>   should be merged. Equally obviously so should [coerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coerce), [type-coercion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-coercion)
>   and [coercion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coercion). With the remaining three tags [type-conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-conversion),
>   [type-coercion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-coercion) and [type-casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-casting), I'd be hesitant to merge any
>   further. At least to me, these are not synonyms

Comment: In Haskell, at least, "coercion" is always explicit. I don't think there's necessarily much in common between how exactly the words break down across language families, so yeah, I guess the conservative approach is best, but the tag descriptions should all link to each other.